# Javascript date format without timezone

Tags: javascript, date

I have a javascript variable which is defined from an input value.

```
$d = $('#date').val();
$myDateParts = $d.split("-");
$dflip = new Date($myDateParts[2], ($myDateParts[1]-1), $myDateParts[0]);
console.log($dflip);

$dflip = Wed Sep 19 00:00:00 UTC+0100 2012
```

How can i format the output to just:

```
Wed Sep 19
```

Comment: Look at this blog article. It explains a lot on how to format Date in javascript. It have what you need now and also other format that maybe useful down the road. http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format This StackOverflow article also have something similar to what you need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: @Steven  That blogpost recommends using a date formatting module embedded into the post.  Surely there is a better builtin way?

Answer (score 4):

You can do something using `substring` or `toDateString` or both

for e.g:

```
var dateString = new Date(2012, 0, 31).toDateString();
var noYear = dateString.substring(0, dateString.length-5);
console.log(noYear);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with following code.

```
<script src="../../ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "D M yy", dflip.val());
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the cleanest, most efficient or best way to accomplish what you're looking for, but I created a function to return the date without the timezone. You can adjust the "theDate" variable to return only the parts of the date you want.

```
    function properDate(){  

    var d = new Date();

    var DayOfMonth = d.getDate();
    var DayOfWeek = d.getDay();
    var Month = d.getMonth();
    var Year = d.getFullYear();
    var Hours = d.getHours();
    var Minutes = d.getMinutes();
    var Seconds = d.getSeconds();

    switch (DayOfWeek) {
    case 0:
        day = "Sun";
        break;
    case 1:
        day = "Mon";
        break;
    case 2:
        day = "Tue";
        break;
    case 3:
        day = "Wed";
        break;
    case 4:
        day = "Thu";
        break;
    case 5:
        day = "Fri";
        break;
    case 6:
        day = "Sat";
        break;
    }

    switch (Month) {
    case 0:
        month = "Jan";
        break;
    case 1:
        month = "Feb";
        break;
    case 2:
        month = "Mar";
        break;
    case 3:
        month = "Apr";
        break;
    case 4:
        month = "May";
        break;
    case 5:
        month = "Jun";
        break;
    case 6:
        month = "Jul";
        break;
    case 7:
        month = "Aug";
        break;
    case 8:
        month = "Sep";
        break;
    case 9:
        month = "Oct";
        break;
    case 10:
        month = "Nov";
        break;
    case 11:
        month = "Dec";
        break;
    }




    var theDate = day + " " + month + " " + DayOfMonth + "  " + Year + " " + Hours + ":" + Minutes + ":" + Seconds;

    return theDate; 
}
```

Comment: Why `switch` instead of just populating an array?

Comment: Honest answer, the switch for the "day" values was already created for a W3 Schools example so it was easy to re-purpose. A two dimensional array would be cleaner.

Comment: Only one dimension Array is needed

Answer (score 0):

My DateExtentions library will do that - although  it may be overkill if all you're doing is that one, simple format.

http://depressedpress.com/javascript-extensions/dp_dateextensions/

I can parse the date based on a passed mask and format the output however you like (it'll also do all sorts of date math and utility stuff so again, it might be heavier than you need).